# How can I avoid typechecking in this situation

Tags: java, typechecking

The situation is the following:

We have a game where there are players and items. The game is won when a player has all 3 specific items in their inventory and assembles them (there is only 1 of each of them on the map). Items have a very simple interface, the player can call `use()` on them. There are other classes implementing the `Item` interface that have been left out of the snippet. If I were to ignore basic OOP principles I could just say that when the player uses one of these then we iterate over the player's inventory and check if all 3 of these specific types of items are in it. How do I avoid doing this?

```
public interface Item{
    public void use();
}

public class SpecificItem1 implements Item{
    public void use(){...}
}

public class SpecificItem2 implements Item{
    public void use(){...}
}

public class SpecificItem3 implements Item{
    public void use(){...}
}

public class Player{

    ArrayList<Item> inventory;

    public void didWeWin() {

        int numOfSItems = 0;

        for(Item i : inventory) {
            if(i instanceOf SpecificItem1)
                numOfSItems++;
            if(i instanceOf SpecificItem2)
                numOfSItems++;
            if(i instanceOf SpecificItem3)
                numOfSItems++;
        }

        if(numOfSItems == 3)
            win();
    }

}
```

Comment: You're always calling `numOfSItems++` for all cases, you can just delete the `if`s entirely.

Comment: Are there other classes implementing `Item` interface? If not, and as you said "there is only 1 of each of them on the map", you can just check the size of the `inventory`

Comment: There are other classes implementing the ```Item``` interface

Answer (score 4):

You could use `getClass()` to get an item's class, and then count the number of unique ones:

```
public void didWeWin() {
   if (inventory.stream().map(Object::getClass).distinct().count() == 3L) {
       win();
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually, if you read the question carefully, it says "there is only 1 of each of them on the map" - you could just check that lists size. Unless there are other classes implementing the interface, but that information is missing from the question

Answer (score 0):

In case the inventory might contain other kinds of item which are not part of the win condition, checking that there are at least three different kinds of item is insufficient. In that case, you can use the [`containsAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection-) method to check for the classes of item required for the win condition.

```java
// List.of works in Java 9+, use Arrays.asList for Java 8
private static List<Class<?>> WIN_CONDITION
    = List.of(SpecificItem1.class, SpecificItem2.class, SpecificItem3.class);

public boolean hasWon() {
    return inventory.stream()
        .map(Object::getClass)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet())
        .containsAll(WIN_CONDITION);
}
```